# Invoking JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, c#, dotnetbrowser

How to invoke JavaScript function written in the HTML from .cs file?

For the Microsoft's Winform control `WebBrowser` we can invoke the JavaScript function as

```
Browser.Document.InvokeScript("JavascriptFunction");
```

We can also pass the parameters from C# to JavaScript function.

How we can achieve this for DotNetBrowser control?

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved. I was missing the braces for the function name. The correct way is browser.ExecuteJavaScript("FunctionName()")